# writing my own libcamera-app

Tags: c++, libcamera

I used to be quite an experienced c programmer but, just after cpp appeared, we all switched to java. Now I am rather lost with make, cmake, ninja, git, pip3, meson ... It makes dealing with java's classpath look easy.  Anyway, I have successfully followed the directions and can compile and install the  libcamera-apps.

What I can't do is make my own. The use-case is to write libcamera_myApp.cpp which looks exactly like libcamera_hello.cpp and incorporate it into something big - lets assume something in java using JNI. That is, I don't want it under libcamera/apps/.

So the standard:

```
sudo make install
```

puts stuff in /usr/local/include/libcamera-apps/ and /usr/local/include/libcamera/ and I can export CPATH appropriately and replace double quotes with angle brackets in the include statements, but now I am lost.

```
std::optional<T> get(const Control<T> &ctrl) const
```

gives

```
error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
```

Is this saying I have failed to include something, or is this the fact I have not linked anything yet, or is it something else? The message is wrong in that std does name a template, but it can't find it.

The code I want to write is simple, but the build process! Not sure I am asking the right question, to the right forum but, well, any pointers would be much appreciated.  Indeed I think I ought to be writing a libcamera post-processor (for AprilTag fiducials) but, again, although there is nice sample code to create a post-processor,I still need to be able to compile and link it.

Having spent another 2 hours on it, it seems it is using a different cpp compiler - +17 or something.  Perhaps the libcamera people could give an example of a stand alone app that uses the libraries.

Several days later..the answer is (almost):

```
gcc -std=c++17 -o libcamera_hello -I/home/pi/libcamera-apps -I/usr/include/libcamera libcamera_hello.cpp -lcamera-base -lcamera -lcamera_app
```

... but not quite. This gives

```
... undefined reference to '_ZTVSt9exception@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
```

Tried pkg-config to no avail, and I assume there is some kind of give-away in the CMake files or meson files somewhere but I am grep-ing for the wrong thing obviously.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *just after cpp appeared, we all switched to java* - did cpp cause mass brain damage?

Comment: c++ was released in 1985, java not until 10 years later. What did you do in the interim? I manage most coding without using either.

Comment: I have an original copy of Kernighan and Ritchie (85) which I used for 10 years; Like C had before it, java addressed a whole lot of issues we were having - including libraries and how to find them - and so we all switched. Cpp has the goodies these days, but it also has the legacy ... like assuming that you don't need pkg-config or that some form of Makefile will list all the use cases. GLIBXX error seems to mean package conflict, which seems odd on a fresh install of PiOS with the RaspberryPi documented camera. Any ideas?

Comment: Re read the comment and saw my mistake - modified the response. but took too long.  I used C for a long time before deciding that there was something worthwhile in this OOP craze.  Used CPP for about 18 months before "discovering" java. (K&R is 1978 btw)

Comment: Stuff like this: `error: 'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type` is just C++ basics and should be researched that way.  It's an almost absurdly complex language with a long history and has been constantly evolving over the past 10-15 years, but it is very widely used and extensively documented.  Do yourself a favour and look around for a decent, recent book covering C++20 or at least C++17.  If you try and just crib this stuff on the fly with google it will bury you. Note that compiler support on RpiOs lags a little, but it still does most of the C++20 stuff...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer I was after was that I can indeed compile libcamera_hello from the command line after downloading the libcamera_apps package as follows:

```
gcc -std=c++17 -o libcamera_hello -I/home/pi/libcamera-apps -I/usr/include/libcamera libcamera_hello.cpp -lstdc++ -lcamera-base -lcamera -lcamera_app
```

I still do not know how this relates to the provided CMake or meson files.  It was trial and error and googling.